# Flatten Files in Subfolders on Windows 7 (cmd or PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, cmd, robocopy

I have a large volume of files organized in a very hierarchical folder structure. In this structure, the file that I care about is always located in the lowest level of the folders. As such, I'd like to flatten the directory so that it's easier to access the files that I care about. However, I'd like to preserve the 2 higher levels (Person & Project) of the folder structure.

Here's an example of the **EXISTING** folder directory:

- Directory

  - Tom

    - Project 1

      - Subfolder Level A

        - *FileA*
      - *FileB*
    - Project 2

      - Subfolder Level C

        - *FileC*
      - *FileD*
  - Jerry

    - Project 1

      - Subfolder Level E

        - *FileE*

Here's an example of the **DESIRED** folder directory:

- Directory

  - Tom

    - Project 1

      - *FileA*
      - *FileB*
    - Project 2

      - *FileC*
      - *FileD*
  - Jerry

    - Project 1

      - *FileE*

I have tried doing something like this, however this flattens all of the files into a single directory:

`for /r %f in (*) do @copy "%f" .`

However, this produces:

- Directory

  - *FileA*
  - *FileB*
  - *FileC*
  - *FileD*
  - *FileE*

I'd appreciate any guidance that you can offer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked @ScottC's answer and used the following code:

```
for /D %%n in (*) do (
    pushd %%n
    for /D %%p in (*) do (
        pushd %%p
        for /r %%f in (*.ppt) do (
            move "%%f" "[ROOT_PATH_THAT_I_WANT]\%%n\%%p".
        )
        popd
    )
    popd
)
```

I ran this solution as a .bat file, which is why I used %% instead of %.

%%n = name (aka C:\Directory\Name)
%%p = project (aka C:\Directory\Name\Project)
%%f = file to be moved (recursively drilling through the folders and moving them up to the project level)

Ultimately, I wasn't able to get @dbenham's suggestion of deleting the empty folders to work, so I ended up using this utility: http://www.jonasjohn.de/red.htm. So far it seems pretty intuitive and like it's taking care of the problem without much effort from me :)

Thanks for the help everybody!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Powershell approach. It gets a list of the folders at the level that you want. Then it moves all the sub files up to that level. it will also remove the sub folders.

```
$Rootfolder = Dir directory\*\* -Directory 

ForEach($folder in $Rootfolder)
{
    Dir $folder.fullname -Recurse -File | Copy-Item -Destination $folder.fullname
    Dir $folder.fullname -Recurse -Directory | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -WhatIf
}
```

If you want it to delete, remove the -WhatIf from the last line.

Answer (score 2):

Throw a couple of extra for loops around the one that works then.

e.g. First change to the name folder, then the project folder, looping through both levels.

```
for /D %n in (*) do (
    pushd %n
    for /D %p in (*) do (
        pushd %p
        for /r %f in (*) do @copy "%f" .
        popd
    )
    popd
)
```

If you put this in a bat file, remember to replace % with %%

Comment: After the COPY you may want to add `for /d %f in (*) do rd /s /q >nul` to get rid of the unwanted sub-folders.

Comment: If you do wish to add cleanup, then `move` the files instead of `copy` and add the extra for statement (suggested by @dbenham) prior to the first popd

Comment: @ScottC - thanks a lot for the help. I used move, but had to hard code part of the path of where to move it.

Comment: @dbenham - thanks for the suggestion. I'm having trouble figuring out where to make that change so that I don't also delete the files that I care about, however I found [this](http://www.jonasjohn.de/red.htm) utility that I think will delete all of the now empty folders for me.

Comment: @KingOfTheNerds - I think this answer needs an extra loop to stop it from attempting to copy a file onto itself. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27538372/1012053)

Comment: @dbenham - you're correct. This was trying to copy files onto itself. I'll post my final solution below (it looks very similar to your revised code). Thanks for the help!

Comment: I had to use "for /d %%f in (*) do rmdir "%%f" /s /q" to remove the directory's

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
pushd yourDirectory
for /d %%A in (*) do for /d %%B in ("%%A\*") do for /d %%C in ("%%B\*") do (
  pushd "%%C"
  for /r %%F in (*) do move /y "%%F" "%%B" >nul
  popd
  rd /q /s "%%C"
)
popd
```

%%A contains something like "yourDirectory\Tom"

%%B contains something like "yourDirectory\Tom\Project 1"

%%C contains something like "yourDirectory\Tom\Project 1\subdirectory1"
%%F contains a file to move, to any depth

At first I thought I could eliminate PUSHD/POPD and use

```
for /r "%%C" %%F in (*) do ...  THIS DOES NOT WORK
```

But that doesn't work - the value after /R cannot use a FOR variable or delayed expansion because of how the command is parsed.